# Why am I in front of two different decimal separators on the same line?

Tags: angular, typescript

Being in France where the decimal separator is the comma, I wrote this component that displays a line where:

- two numbers are decimal (`commune.population` and `commune.surface` have the `number` type)
- but show unexpectedly both different decimal separators: a point for the surface, a comma for the density.

*Commune de 176016 habitants et de 80.03 km² (densité : 2,199)

de l'intercommunalité Saint-Etienne Métropole*

Why is it so?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="presentation_cadre" id="presentation_cadre">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="isCommuneSelected()" [ngIfElse]="pasDeCommuneSelectionnee">
      <div>
        <h4>{{ commune.nomCommune }} ({{ commune.nomDepartement }} ({{ commune.codeDepartement }}))</h4>

        <small>
          <div>Commune de {{ commune.population }} habitants et de {{ commune.surface / 100.0 }} km² (densité : {{ this.getDensitePopulation() | number:'1.0-0' }})</div>
          <div>de l'intercommunalité {{ commune.nomEPCI }}</div>
        </small>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #pasDeCommuneSelectionnee>
      Les informations sur une commune s'afficheront ici
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
public getDensitePopulation() : number {
  if (this.commune == null || this.commune.surface == 0) {
    return 0
  }

  let surfaceKm2 = this.commune.surface / 100.00; // La surface est exprimée en hectares
  return this.commune.population / surfaceKm2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the density, you're using a [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe), which does the following (straight from docs):

> Formats a value according to digit options and **locale rules**. Locale determines group sizing and separator, decimal point character, and other locale-specific configurations.

Since the current locale is FR (France), it formats it using a comma. You could format the number according to the locale yourself pretty easily with `toLocaleString`:

```js
// NOTE: I only pass "FR" here to show what the French locale would output.
// NOTE: It is an optional parameter, where if you don't provide it, it will
// NOTE: default to the locale of the user
console.log((80.03).toLocaleString("FR"));
```

So that would look like this for you:

```
{{ (commune.surface / 100.0).toLocaleString() }}
```

Reference: [MDN Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Although, to be more consistent, you should just use another DecimalPipe for the area.

Comment: Thanks! Applied where it lacked, it corrects the string → `Commune de 176 016 habitants et de 80,03 km² (densité : 2,199)`. The space thousand separator we have is used too, then, if I apply `toLocalString()` on `commune.population` too. I didn't passed an argument to `toLocalString()` to allow the user to have the choice it made on his own computer selected.